# React MaterialUi Date Picker throws RangeError Invalid time value

Tags: react-native, datepicker, material-ui

I've tried about everything I could find on the forums etc,  re this error, but no success.
Most solutions seem to be

```js
format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
```

or
Moment (being locale driven)

I return the selected date into a `chip` which displays fine, but the 'RangeError.Invalid time value' issue persists into the chip after the correct selected date is rendered in it.

```js
const [effectiveSelectedDate, setEffSelectedDate] = useState();
const handleEffDateChange = (date,name) =>{
        setEffSelectedDate(date);
}

export const makeColumns = (columns, language, rawFilters, filters, format_functions) => {
    return columns.map((item, i) => {
        if (data.className.search("date_time") > -1) {
            logic:   (..........                         ),
            display: (filterList, onChange, index, column) => (
                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider
                        utils={DateFnsUtils}
                        locale={localeMap[i18next.language]} >

                    <KeyboardDatePicker    
                        fullWidth
                        variant='inline'
                        placeholder='yyyy-MM-dd'
                        format='yyyy-MM-dd'
                        margin='normal'
                        id='date-picker-inline'
                        name='effectiveDate'
                        value={effectiveSelectedDate}
                        onChange={handleEffDateChange}
                        KeyboardButtonProps={{ 'aria-label': 'change date',  }}
                    />
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
             )
       }
    }
);
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: You need to make sure you are using version 1 of whatever @dateio package you're using (Assuming that this is material UI v 4). Try deleting your node modules if you had to make packge updates and it still didnt work with `rm -rf ndoe_modules` then install and try again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this one

```
const [effectiveSelectedDate, setEffSelectedDate] = useState();
const handleEffDateChange = (date,name) =>{
        setEffSelectedDate(date);
    }
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
           <KeyboardDatePicker
               fullWidth
               variant='inline'
               placeholder='yyyy-MM-dd'
               format='yyyy-MM-dd'
               margin='normal'
               id='date-picker-inline'
               name='effectiveDate'
               value={effectiveSelectedDate}
               onChange={handleEffDateChange}
               KeyboardButtonProps={{
                  'aria-label': 'change date',
                   }}
                       />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: I get this, React Hook "useState" is called in function "makeColumns" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react. I guess I probably should edit the question/code a bit (kinda new to React).

Comment: I have edited the code in the question to provide clarity